# ReactJS: fetch function - Is it possible to make a PUT request?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, reactjs

This is how I currently make a PUT request:

```
var data = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'number': 'TEST12345'
}

var post = {
    "number": "TEST12345",
    "parameters":
    {
        "START_NUMBER" : {
          "value": 5,
          "effectiveDate": "2016/01/01 10:10"
        }
    }
}

var myInit = {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: data,
  body: JSON.stringify(post)
};

fetch('http://localhost:8080/form/upload/post/save', myInit)
.then(result=>{console.log(result.json())})
```

So I was wondering if it's possible to do the same but for a PUT request? If so how can I go about doing so?

Comment: Have you tried changing `method` to `'PUT'`?

Comment: @MikeC but where would I pass in the edit with the request?

Comment: @MikeC just checking to see if you've read my previous comment. please let me know!

Comment: I would assume in the `body`. I'm not familiar with your exact setup.